# Pillow Rotate is losing Alpha Values

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, alpha

I'm using the Alpha value of certain pixels to track their position during a rotate. I've noticed that I am losing the set Alpha value in some instances. Example code showing the problem :

```
 def showAlphas(rotation, img):
        imgPixels = img.load()
        foundAlpha = False
        for w in range(0, img.width):
            for h in range(0, img.height):
                if imgPixels[w, h][3]==50:
                    print 'Found at {}, {} in Rotation {}'.format(w, h, rotation)
                    foundAlpha = True
        if not foundAlpha:
            print 'Alpha missing from rotation {}'.format(rotation)

img = Image.new('RGBA', (100, 50), color='black')
img.putpixel((10, 10), (255, 0, 0, 50))

for x in range(1, 360, 1):
        rotated = img.rotate(x, expand=True)
        showAlphas(x, rotated)
```

Sample output :

```
Found at 96, 41 in Rotation 194
Found at 96, 41 in Rotation 195
Alpha missing from rotation 196
Found at 98, 41 in Rotation 197
Found at 97, 41 in Rotation 198
Found at 98, 41 in Rotation 198
Alpha missing from rotation 199
Alpha missing from rotation 200
Found at 98, 41 in Rotation 201
Found at 97, 40 in Rotation 202
Found at 98, 40 in Rotation 202
```

Using Pillow 5.3.0

Am I doing something wrong in the rotate? As far as I am aware, the Expand=True is the only option I need to specify (to ensure image is not clipped in certain orientations) ?

I am not tied to using Pillow, but needed something to track specific pixel coords in various resize and rotate operations and thought using Pillow and tracking Alpha values would do this. I don't really want to try and track via RGB values, but fear this may be subject to the same issue. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: It is not guaranteed that every pixel in a source image will appear in the result when rotated. Basically, you are rotating one raster (grid) on top of another and at each position in the output raster you either calculate the new point by linear or cubic interpolation or by nearest neighbour to the pixels on the source  rather. You **may** have more luck with `PIL.Image.NEAREST` resampling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I am that good at illustrating what I was saying in the comments - I was hoping to find a brilliant animation on Wikipedia but failed miserably. Anyway, what I was saying is that there is not a one-to-one correspondence between pixels in an input image and those in the output image after rotation.

Sometimes you use interpolation and that means values are scaled between a number of neighbours and a whole new set of pixel values crops up in the output image that are not present in the input image (imagine rotating a black image on a white one and some spots may end up grey), and sometimes you choose NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR and no new pixel values are introduced into the image.

Either way, here is a graphic I made trying to illustrate a rotation. You have two images, one is red and one is black and the pixels are at the intersections of the lines. One image is rotated above the other about the centre pixel so that is the same in the black and the red image.

Look now at the pixel I have boxed with green. It doesn't make it into the output image, because the 4 corners around it are all nearer to other pixels in the original image. So I am saying that the original pixels jump along the blue lines into the output image but the green one doesn't make it... hope you get the idea!

[image]

Comment: Yes this makes sense, thanks for taking the time top explain, I am now taking a different approach.